# internal server error при открытии сайта по ip

Tags: nginx, centos, apache2

Есть сервер. На нем несколько сайтов.  Сайты сами по себе открывается нормально - все ок. Но если открыть сайт по ip(без домена) то выводится internal server error. Как это справить? Где копать? В логах apache нет ничего.  И в гугл не могу найти чтолибо связанное именно с этим(может не правильно ищу). Где копать?

Comment: А зачем это исправлять? Какой сайт вы хотите показать?

Comment: Какой либо из существующих.  Либо дефолтную страничку мол "доступ по ip запрещен"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В nginx есть параметр default server. Используйте его.

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;
    ...
}
```

Comment: мне кажется этот параметр назначит один из сайтов на этот ip адрес. я верно понял?

Comment: не помогло...я думаю что это скорее связано с apache нежели с nginx

Comment: и как можно убедится что связка nginx+apache работает корректно?

Comment: да, один из сайтов назначается на этот адрес. Перейдите по адресу 139.59.153.194 - это IP моего сервера, там много сайтов. Я как раз сейчас для проверки поставил сайт kagg.eu как сайт по умолчанию так, как в моем ответе. Как видите, работает. На ошибку по безопасности не обращайте внимания, потому что у меня сертификат не содержит ip адреса

Comment: Вам надо просто добавить параметр default_server в уже существующую секцию server. Все должно работать.

Comment: не сработало....таже ошибка 500....логика ведь такая что nginx берет данные у apache. а apache дает ему с 500....кстати я проверил данные на Network в браузере..итог эта страница ошибки отдается от nginx...значит дело в апач

Comment: скорее всего, да. У меня никакого apache нет, потому и работает )

Comment: Этот ответ оказался почти верным.  Единственное, нужно было  назначит дефолтный сайт еще и в конфигах апача